# Change the color of text selection

Tags: javascript

I understand that there is a CSS pseudo-element `::seleсtion`. But nevertheless, I need it, because I learn JavaScript. Here's the code to which I came, but it does not work:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    var txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode(txt);
    var rng = document.createRange();
    rng.setStart(txtNode, 0);
    rng.setEnd(txtNode, txt.length);
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    rng.surroundContents(span);
}, false);
```

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what's not working. So you need `::selection`, or in other words? "You're learning JS so you need it" does not explains your issue and what's the desired output. Simply color it in green? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection

Comment: I want to change the color of a standard selection with JavaScript.

Comment: This approach will have lots of HTML elements everywhere though, is there a particular reason you want to do it like this?

Comment: It's not that easy. You must split the selected nodes in their selected and non selected parts, and then wrap the selected ones in an element, e.g. `span`, which you can style like you want. There are edge cases like selection among nested elements. I think once I answered a duplicate (or similar) question, but can't find it.

Comment: @Oriol, I'm already half a day trying to do - it is impossible. Tried in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until that happened only highlight. What more do to when clicking on an empty space allocation reset?

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup' , function(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

    range.surroundContents(span);
} , false);
```